# How to cascade included templates in Text::Xslate?

Tags: perl, templates, text-xslate

In [Text::Xslate](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Xslate) is great way to `cascade` (or wrap, in some other templating engine) specific template into main template. There is also possible to `include` common chunks into template.

I'd like to `include` chunks into specific template which `cascade`s into main template, but in a way that `include`d template has parts which replace (`around` keyword) some named-parts in main.

Simplified test case

#### main.pl

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use FindBin qw($Bin);
use Text::Xslate;

my $tx = Text::Xslate->new(
    path => [ "$Bin/template" ],
);

print $tx->render( 'some.tx' );
```

#### template/some.tx

```
: cascade main

: around some -> {

some text 1

: include included;

some text 2
: }
```

#### template/main.tx

```
MAIN template

: block main -> { 
  main DEFAULT text, should replaced with included.tx one
: } # 

: block some -> { 
: } #
```

#### template/included.tx

```
: around main -> { 
  this should come from included but does not
: }  

included successfully into some.tx
```

#### Desired output

```
MAIN template

  this should come from included but does not


some text 1


included successfully into some.tx


some text 2
```

So the third line in the output is not right, if I use it in `some.tx`

```
: around main -> { 
  this should come from included but does not
: }
```

it works.

But how to include chunks, which should cascade into main-template?

Answer (score 0):

Try [`cascade ... with`](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/SKAJI/Text-Xslate-v3.5.6/lib/Text/Xslate/Syntax/Kolon.pm#Template-cascading):

#### template/some.tx

```perl
: cascade main with included
: around some -> {
some text 1
: include included;
some text 2
: }
```